# Connect to Hbase1.2 with spark 2.1

Tags: maven, apache-spark, hbase

Simple code following offical doc:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp")
                .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        Configuration cfg = HBaseConfiguration.create();
//        cfg.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");
        JavaHBaseContext hc = new JavaHBaseContext(sc, cfg);

        JavaRDD<List<String>> rdd = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(Tom, Jerry));
        System.out.println(rdd.collect());


    }
```

And pom in Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-spark</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-alpha-1</version>
</dependency>
```

I get an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/spark/Logging

How fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

org/apache/spark/Logging was removed after spark 1.5.2. So I think you are getting this error.

Can you try to put spark-core_2.11-1.5.2.logging.jar separately under your project jar directory and rerun your application.